# Download already segmented files with NIO - Java 11

Tags: java, file, httpclient, nio, segment

I want to download a huge file that is already split into hundreds of segments into a single file.

So I have all of the URL-s of all of the segments in an array, I divide it by hand into 4 sections, start 4 threads at the same time then merge them at the end into a single huge file.
The part where I think I could improve my code is at the part when I download the sections. The goal is to open the files once, and append all segments into them.
I'm open for completely other solutions too.

```
static void downloadFileSection(int begin, int end, int marker, String[] segmentURLs, String segID) {
        try(var file = FileChannel.open(Path.of(segID + "_" + marker + ".seg"), WRITE, CREATE)){
            var byteArrayHandler = BodyHandlers.ofByteArray();

            IntStream.range(begin, end)
                      .forEach(index -> {

                          System.out.println("Downloading segment: " + index);

                          try {
                              //This is the part that I think is wrong. I shouldn't be creating a ByteBuffer every segment download.
                              //Main.sendNormalRequest is a method that sends a request using java 11-s HttpClient.send method.
                              file.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(Main.sendNormalRequest(segmentURLs[index], byteArrayHandler).body()));
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      });
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Do you want to minimize memory usage or do you want to parallel the process?

Comment: I want to know if there's a better way to download many small files into a single one, basically appending all the bytes. Talking about memory usage I noticed that eclipse memory analyzer mentions that the HttpClient is keeping references to the ByteBuffers.

Comment: The "fastest" method would be to execute several calls to the small files parallel (e.g. queue them via `ThreadPoolExecutor`) and then write the parts into the target file via a single `RandomAccessFile` by copying the InputStream from the HTTP connection to the RAF-OutputStream. That should also have the lowest memory footprint because you don't load the files completely into the RAM.

Comment: The HttpClient uses different strategies depending on whether the request goes through HTTPS or plain HTTP. In general it may forward buffer slices to the caller code in order to optimize memory usage - which may appear as if it's holding reference to the byte buffer, whereas it may just be waiting for the next bytes to fill the next slice. With HTTPS then there are temporary byte buffers which are used between the socket and the SSL Engine: these are typically recycled and the HttpClient will keep a reference on them as they never escape to the caller, but there should be only a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [BodyHandlers.ofPublisher()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html#ofPublisher()) to obtain a `Publisher<List<ByteBuffer>>`. Then if the status is 200 OK, provide and subscribe your own `Flow.Subscriber<List<ByteBuffer>>` implementation and write the bytes to the file as they come in the `onNext(...)` method. If these bytes represent text then you might have to take care about character encoding/transcoding especially if you need to write the file in a different encoding than what is sent by the server (usually that will be UTF-8).